# Get Set Properties remove time from datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I remove time portion from `DateTime` within Get Set Properties

The below code is not working and I tried a few ways. I also tried `dateValue.ToString("d")`

```
private DateTime dateValue;

public DateTime DateValue
{
   get
    {
       //First Try
       return dateValue.ToShortDateString;
       //Second Try
       return dateValue.ToString("d")
       //Third Try
       DateTime dateValue = DateTime.????(not sure)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property.

```
DateTime dateValue = dateValue.Date;
```

So it would be

```
private DateTime dateValue;

public DateTime DateValue
{
   get
   {          
      return dateValue.Date;
   }
}
```

Comment: Damn. Beat me to the punch ;) +1

Comment: @SimonBelanger You got a +1 actually for including the `return` :)

Comment: when writing it this way there is no .Date value.

Comment: Ok .Date showed up and gave no errors but when I run the project my gridview still adds a time to the date. I was trying to avoid using the "d" inside the gridview to just display date and learn how to accomplish this in the properties. Any reason why this is still sending a time value also?

Comment: @user2539281 I didn't realise you were using a GridView. Could you post the GridView binding code please.

Comment: <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="dateValue" 
                HeaderText="DATE" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>

Comment: i know you can add {0:d} to the dataformatstring but is it not possible to do this from the get set property accesors without messing with the inline code of the gridview

Comment: Personally I'd go for simply using the `DataFormatString` because that side is related to the user interface whereas the backend is for the logic. Generally, the backend shouldn't really care how the data is going to be presented to the user, it generally just provides the data and the front end (`BoundField` in this case) should choose how that data is to be represented (with `DataFormatString`). I'm not familiar enough with the GridView to know how to force the property to choose the formatting other than converting the DateTime to a short string and returning the string.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `Date`:

```
return dateValue.Date;
```